# Is a transaction automatically rollbacked when 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; ...' error occurs? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, rollback

I got **the error below** in a transaction in **MySQL**:

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
> transaction

So, when **the error above** occurs, is the transaction automatically rollbacked?

Or with **the MySQL query below**, do I need manually rollback the transaction?

```sql
ROLLBACK;
```